# Number of images only follows the int once

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a row of pencils in the HStack according to the "number" var and a person if the number is zero. But I couldn't figure out why the image only follows the number when it is 0 or 1. I can click the add button and make the number to 100 and there is still only one pencil.

Thank you so much.

Excerpt of my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var number: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
      VStack{
                HStack{
                    if number == 0 {
                        Image(systemName: "person")
                        } else {
                            ForEach(0..<self.number){_ in
                                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(action:{self.add()})
                {
                    Text("add")
                }
                Button(action:{self.subtract()})
                {
                    Text("substract")
                }
                Text("\(number)")
        }
    }
    
    func add(){
        number += 1
        return
    }
    
    func subtract(){
        number -= 1
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use constant-data `ForEach` constructor, try instead

```
HStack{
    if number == 0 {
        Image(systemName: "person")
        } else {
            ForEach(Array(0..<self.number), id: \.self){_ in  // << here !!
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
        }
    }
}
```